How can I mock an async generic cache factory using Moq?
I am trying to mock the following method of a caching service using Moq:
Task<TItem> GetOrCreateAsync<TItem>(string key, Func<Task<TItem>> factory)

The method normally checks a cache for an entry and returns it, or if not found it creates a new instance by calling the factory. I want to create a mock that simply calls the factory and returns the result back to the caller.
Here is a minimal, reproducible example (LINQPad Instant Share):
var mock = new Mock<ICache>();
mock.Setup(cache => cache.GetOrCreateAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<Task<It.IsAnyType>>>()).Result)
  .Returns((string b, Func<Task<object>> c) => c().Result);

mock.Object.GetOrCreateAsync("test", () => Task.FromResult(123));

public interface ICache
{
  Task<TItem> GetOrCreateAsync<TItem>(string key, Func<Task<TItem>> factory);   
}

When I run the above I get an InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[Moq.It+IsAnyType]' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[System.Int32]'.
Any ideas?

What is the signature of GetOrCreateAsync?

Can't reproduce. Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Minimal reproducible example added.

The error message already explains what the problem is. Task<It+AnyType> isn't compatible with Task<int>. The easiest way to address the issue is to use the appropriate type arguments:
[Fact]
public async Task Repro()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ICache>();
    mock.Setup(cache => cache.GetOrCreateAsync(
            It.IsAny<string>(),
            It.IsAny<Func<Task<int>>>()))
      .Returns((string b, Func<Task<int>> c) => c());

    await mock.Object.GetOrCreateAsync("test", () => Task.FromResult(123));
}

This test passes without any exceptions.
If you want to have some sort of reusable setup, use generics in the way they were intended. It may be simplest to first set up a helper method:
private static void SetupCache<T>(Mock<ICache> mock, T returnValue)
{
    mock.Setup(cache => cache.GetOrCreateAsync(
            It.IsAny<string>(),
            It.IsAny<Func<Task<T>>>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(returnValue);
}

Notice that this method is generic in T, which means that you can call it with various different type arguments:
[Fact]
public async Task CacheInt()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ICache>();
    SetupCache(mock, 42);
    
    var actual =
        await mock.Object.GetOrCreateAsync("test", () => Task.FromResult(123));
    
    Assert.Equal(42, actual);
}

[Fact]
public async Task CacheString()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ICache>();
    SetupCache(mock, "foo");
    
    var actual =
        await mock.Object.GetOrCreateAsync("test", () => Task.FromResult("bar"));
    
    Assert.Equal("foo", actual);
}

Both of these tests pass.

Thank you Mark. I was hoping for a more general solution leveraging the It.IsAnyType feature, but in lieu of that your solution is the most straightforward.

Mocking an async function return value should use ReturnsAsync rather than Returns. Once you get that fixed, I would also use more specific objects in the mock setup based on the specific test.

According to https://github.com/devlooped/moq/wiki/Quickstart#async-methods ReturnsAsync is no longer required.

Learn something new every day!

I'm curious why you didn't return an object instead of a lambda function. It seems like it doesn't like the difference between what you declared it needed as an input in the mock and the lambda inside returns.
